# jQuery | Select hyperlink's element text | text() or html() methods seems not to be working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<a href=#>Title</a>` link and it's the **text** in between `<a href="#">` attribute that I want to select but can't get it working using either `text()` or `html()` jQuery methods.

The `text()` is returning nothing and the `html()` is returning *undefined*.

**How can I select the text within the hyperlink attribute using jQuery?**

```js
var menu = jQuery(".section-items nav-sections-items > .section-item-title > a").html();
  console.log(menu);
  if (menu == "Title Here") {
   console.log("Working");
  }
    
var menu2 = jQuery(".section-items nav-sections-items > .section-item-title > a").text();
  console.log(menu2);
  if (menu2 == "Title Here") {
   console.log("Working");
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-items nav-sections-items">
  <div class="section-item-title">
    <a href="#">Title Here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector is wrong. `.section-items .nav-sections-items` selects the elements having class `.nav-sections-items` under `.section-items`.

In your code, both classes are on the same element, so the space should be removed to denote the same element, having both the classes.

See the demo below:

```js
var menu = jQuery(".section-items.nav-sections-items > .section-item-title > a").html();
console.log(menu);
if (menu == "Title Here") {
  console.log("Working");
}

var menu2 = jQuery(".section-items.nav-sections-items > .section-item-title > a").text();
console.log(menu2);
if (menu2 == "Title Here") {
  console.log("Working");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-items nav-sections-items">
  <div class="section-item-title">
    <a href="#">Title Here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your selector isn't correct

Try
`div.section-items.nav-sections-items > div > a`

```
var menu = jQuery("div.section-items.nav-sections-items > div > a").html();
    console.log(menu);
    if (menu == "Title Here") {
        console.log("Working");
    }

var menu2 = jQuery("div.section-items.nav-sections-items > div > a").text();
    console.log(menu2);
    if (menu2 == "Title Here") {
        console.log("Working");
    }
```

For those that are wondering, my code has `> div > a` instead of `> .section-item-title > a` as in this case, there is virtually no difference - and every kb matters!

Answer (score 1):

You had a wrong way to select element, should use `.section-items.nav-sections-items`:

```js
var menu = jQuery(".section-items.nav-sections-items > .section-item-title > a").html();
  console.log(menu);
  if (menu == "Title Here") {
   console.log("Working");
  }
    
var menu2 = jQuery(".section-items.nav-sections-items > .section-item-title > a").text();
  console.log(menu2);
  if (menu2 == "Title Here") {
   console.log("Working");
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section-items nav-sections-items">
  <div class="section-item-title">
    <a href="#">Title Here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```